# Intercept Angular URL with PHP first before loading webpage

Tags: php, angular, redirect, intercept

We currently have a full Angular project running in a sub-dir on our server and a physical "device" using a hardcoded URL to send a user to that page.

I'm looking for some kind of way to "intercept" the request via a PHP script first to (for example, not the real purpose) see if the requested "ID" param for that browser page has enabled the option to view the browser page or if it has been configured by the user to return a 406 HTTP response (for example).

```
Currently:
- ..com/app/routing-view?id=1234 => Angular view -> fetch info

Idea:
- ..com/app/routing-view?id=1234 => PHP-script -> isValid => forward to angular and do a normal 'webview' -> fetch info
- ..com/app/routing-view?id=2889 => PHP-script -> notValid => HTTP code
```

I thought about having a .htaccess "intercept" the url and forward it to a .php file. Do the magic and checks there, and then forward the browser to the original url, but to "bypass" the previous interceptor.

It's about that last part that I'm currently having issues. Because it's Angular and it is using paths, I can't just say "okay, redirect to index.html instead of index.php" because it would need to be something like `..com/app/routing-view?id=1234` (and the index.html is located in the `/app` directory.

I don't want to add PHP code to the original Angular-index file if that could be avoided.

Am I looking at this right or would there be a different, more efficient way to tackle this?

The reason for all this is that I want to (for example) return a different HTTP code or different headers to the device instead of a 200 html header response even if the ID turned out to be disabled or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work via a simple `.htaccess`, a parameter and an "interceptor" script. Quite simple and basic really, not sure why my brain didn't go this route before posting my question.

1. Added the `.htaccess` to the root of the Angular application with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if the request has been intercepted before (via URL parameter)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)intercepted=true

# .. If not, rewrite the page to use the interceptor script (only if it matches the route).
RewriteRule ^my-route dir-of-script/extra/interceptor.php?url=https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]


# Other stuff for rewriting the Angular routes etc
...
```

2. Added a `/dir-of-script/extra/interceptor.php` like-script that parses the URL from the GET parameter, fetches the info, does the checks and depending on the result, returns the output or redirects the page and let it through.

This adds a `..&intercepted=true` parameter to the original URL so that the `.htaccess` doesn't intercept it again.

This seems to be working like a charm (for my situation). The only "downside" is that this counts as a redirect and not just a rewrite when it was allowed to go through. Will look further into it, to maybe let the PHP script "serve" the Angular content instead of redirecting to it.